# Why are UIScreen.bounds incorrect in iOS11

Tags: swift, ios11

*Please don't mark as duplicate. Available threads haven't provided an answer. Behavior is iOS11 only.*

Updating a project from Xcode 8 to Xcode 9, using now iOS11 but still Swift 3, I have the following experience:

```
    print("UIScreen.main.bounds.width = \(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)")
    print("self.view.frame.width = \(self.view.frame.width)")

    let rect = CGRect(

        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
        height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.25

    )
```

prints:

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.width = 414.0
self.view.frame.width = 600.0
```

The view is supposed to be from screen edge to screen edge. Therefore I have used `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`. But the value far too small for the actual view controller size of `self.view.frame.width`.

Why is that? What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Physical device. Same behavior using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width`

Comment: The plus-sized devices, in portrait mode, do in fact have a point width of 414. If your view's width is 600 it's too wide for the screen.

Comment: But I want a view to be edge to edge. the view is set using the 414 points. But my iPhone 6S plus needs it to be 600 to fill the screen edge to edge....

Comment: So to express myself correctly: the desired view is too small to fill the screen edge to edge because its frame has a width of 414 points... But should have 600(?)

Comment: No, it should have a width of 414. The iPhone 6S Plus has a point resolution of 414 × 736.

Comment: Remember that UIScreen.main.bounds always return the bounds in portrait mode.  If you are working in landscape you should use UIScreen.main.bounds.height which should give you 736.  I like to use max(UIScreen.main.bounds.height, UIScreen.main.bounds,width)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same issue with + devices.

Comment: @ĐorđeNilović unfortunately not. All I got was sassy answers like I'm the dummy

Comment: @DavidSeek How are you putting the view onto the screen? I'm working with a 7+ and can fill with screen with an object at that size.

Comment: in this scenario it was `let view = UIView()` and `self.view.addSubview(view)` so super crazy regular

Comment: Crap can't get it to work either.. any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with incorrect fetching of `UIScreen.main.bounds` size. The size was less than a physical screen. The solution was to add the next line into **info.plst**:

Key:

```
Launch screen interface file base name
```

Type:

```
String
```

Value:

```
LaunchScreen
```

So check your **info.plist** to see if it contains this line. If it's not, just add it. Hope this helps.
[screen shot of info.plst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N9Hz.png)