# Swift - Why is UIScreen.main.bounds behaving differently on different devices?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, screen-size, uiscreen

I am trying to create a game for IOS using SpriteKit. My problem is that different devices outputs different things. This is the code I try:

```
var testPath = CGRect(
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2,
   height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 2
)
var testFill = SKShapeNode(path: CGPath(rect: testPath, transform: nil))

testFill.fillColor = UIColor.black
addChild(testFill)
```

For iPhone 7 this works perfectly. For iPhone 5 I get extra space on top and to the right, the same result for Ipads. For iPhone 7+, however, I go outside the screen.

My first question is, why do I need to take `main.bounds.height * 2` to cover the screen vertically. Shouldn't `* 1` be enough? Secondly and more importantly, why do I get so different results on different devices?

Comment: This is probably caused by the fact that you are designing your screens on iPhone 7 and not resizing the scene properly when the view controller frame changes.

Comment: What is your goal,  do you want everything to take the same amount of screen space up, e.g. a button takes up 25% of the screen on all devices; or do you want to show more scene when you are on screens with larger devices, e.g. a button  will always take up 32 pixels, but you can fit more buttons on an iphone Plus than a regular iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will face many problems should you pursue in this direction!

You should not use the screen size but your view controller's view bounds.
Doing so will avoid size problems, should your app be used in multitask or otherwise...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.bounds) 
    view.addSubview(skView);
    let scene = MyScene(size: view.bounds.size) // <- construct your scene with the screen size
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
```

You can then fill your scene and use the size value to layout your nodes.

Comment: This is only half of the solution. You also have to resize the scene once the controller changes its size.

Comment: Yes you do, but you keep using your controller size, not the main screen size... but yeah, there is some more code to write :)

Comment: You really should not use either.  You should be using constraints when setting up your view, then use a static size for your scene.  If you plan on using the full screen points with no scaling, you set your `scaleMode` to `.resize`, and then use the scenes `bounds` when you need to determine scene size

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check your **info.plst** to see the line about **the launch screen**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749138/13433324

Answer (score 0):

1- According to game logic play space should have more size than screen , so sprites come across from different position , if you set it to only *1 (will fill the entire screen including the statusBar) , added sprite will show in screen instead of bouncing from left to right / bottom to top

2- Every device has it's own different screen size , so it's size * 2 will also be different